One of the LIST command's functionalities do not work in Snowflake
I am using the following Snowflake documentation:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/list
It talks about an option which I interpret as it is showing all other files in the same stage directory as a specified table:
From the document:
@[namespace.]%table_name[/path] - Files are in the stage for the specified table.
Example: LIST @%mytable;
I tried numerous versions in my code but I just can't get it to work eg.:
LIST  @%util_db.public.aws_s3_bucket/currencies.csv;
LIST  @util_db.public.aws_s3_bucket/%currencies.csv;
LIST  @util_db.public.aws_s3_bucket%currencies.csv;

I also tried using quotes but nothing worked.
Util_db.public.aws_s3_bucket is my stage name and currencies.csv is the table (although it is a flat file but in the staging context I thought that qualifies as a table?)
There are definitely other files in util_db.public.aws_s3_bucket (the names of which is my aim to print out with this query) and the names are all correct.
Do I interpret the documentation wrong or is what I am doing possible and if yes, what syntax do I need?

You are misinterpreting what a table stage is, I think.  Every table you create in Snowflake has it's own stage.  This stage is internal to Snowflake and accessed using the syntax you are trying to use.  If you have a file in a stage that you created, then that doesn't qualify as being a table or a table stage.
